# Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-hba.conf

I have been using postgreSQL, trying to dump plain backup file using command:

```
psql -U postgres DATABASE < path to file.backup
```

But getting peer authentication failure. Even tried changing `pg_hba.conf` from `peer` to `md5`, but didn't work.

Comment: peer means you are not OS user `postgres`, while trying to connect as one, `sudo su - postgres` and then `psql DBNAME >file.sql`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me.

Comment: `sudo su - postgres`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`peer` means you are not OS user postgres, while trying to connect as one,

1. `sudo su - postgres`
2. and then `psql DBNAME >file.sql`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER

> The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's
>   operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed
>   database user name (with optional user name mapping). This method is
>   only supported on local connections.